Subquadratic algorithms for approximate graph matching of two undirected trees
I am searching for efficient algorithms to optimize the approximate graph matching (AGM) problem. The general case of this problem is known to be NP-hard (equivalent to the quadratic assignment problem). My question is, which algorithms, deterministic or stochastic, are capable of solving or approximating the AGM problem in subquadratic space and time complexity for two unrooted trees?
Formally, consider two undirected tree-structured graphs $T_1= (V_1, E_1)$, and $T_2 = (V_2, E_2)$, where $n:=|V_1| = |V_2|$. The goal is to find a bijection $M:V_1 \to V_2$ to maximize $|E_{M} \cap E_2|$, where $E_M = \{(M(u), M(v)): (u, v) \in  E_1\}$, in $o(n^2)$ space and time complexity (little-o).
